# A parallelism issue

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel.foreach

I've written 3 different ways of computing a sum of an array of integer, however, I'm getting a different result for the third method.

Initialization:

```
        int n = 100;
        int[] mArray = new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < mArray.Length; i++)          
            mArray[i] = 1;
```

First:

```
        int sum1 = mArray.Sum();
        Console.WriteLine("sum1 " + sum1);
```

Second:

```
        int sum2 = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < mArray.Length; i++)
            sum2 += mArray[i];
        Console.WriteLine("sum2 " + sum2);
```

Third:

```
        int sum3 = 0;
        Parallel.ForEach(mArray, item =>
        {
            sum3 += item;
        });
        Console.WriteLine("sum3 " + sum3);
```

Obviously, the 3 approaches gave the same output as seen below :

[image]

However, when n is increased (e.g., n = 30000), the third approach gives surprisingly false results

[image]

NB: I've tested the approaches using ConcurrentBag which is a thread-safe collection. I suppose, there is no overflow issue. The code is tested on a windows 10 x64 computer (Intel core I-7 @ 3.30ghz)

It would be interesting to understand why Parallel.For behaves differently.

Comment: You're reading and writing to `sum3` from multiple threads. Thats the textbook-example for a race.

Comment: Why do you assume += is thread safe? Simple like that. Interlocked has an add method, me thinks, that is thread safe.

Comment: While locking (whether through `lock` or `Interlocked.Add`) will "solve" this, this is the kind of parallel loop better suited to either `Parallel.For` (where you make the intermediate results explicit) or easier yet parallel LINQ (`mArray.AsParallel().Sum()`). (This is of course assuming parallelism helps at all; often sequential code easily outpaces it on small instances like this, because it has much better memory access patterns and no overhead of context switching.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'have Nick's solution and it fixed the problem, however, there was a performance issue when using 
`lock (objLock) { sum3 += item; }` directly in the Parallel.ForEach, as shown in the figure below

[image]

Fortunatly, using Parallel Aggregation Operations, as properly defined in [.Net](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/aggregation-operations) solved the issue. Here is the code

```
        object locker = new object();
        double sum4= 0;
        Parallel.ForEach(mArray,
                        () => 0.0,                 // Initialize the local value.
                        (i, state, localResult) => localResult + i, localTotal =>   // Body delegate which returns the new local total.                                                                                                                                           // Add the local value
                            {
                                lock (locker) sum4+= localTotal;
                            }    // to the master value.
                        );
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that `sum3` is accessed by multiple threads when you use `Parallel.ForEach`. `sum3 += item;` would normally involve three operations:
1. Read the value of `sum3` into a temporary storage.
2. Increment the value of that storage with `item`;
3. Store the result back to `sum3`.

When multiple threads to this concurrently, it is very likely that operations will get mixed.  For example, if you have two threads, A and B, both may read the same value from `sum3`, then do their adding and store the new values back.

To overcome this issue, you need to protect you access to `sum3`.  The code should look like this:

```
 object objLock = new object();
 int sum3 = 0;
 Parallel.ForEach(mArray, item =>
 {
     lock (objLock) { sum3 += item; }
 });
 Console.WriteLine("sum3 " + sum3);
```

But, that will totally negate the effect of the parallel execution.

Comment: A lock is unnecessary, an atomic operation does the job just as good: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked.add?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: Atomic operations will do great for primitive types.  My idea for moral was that concurrent operations require some kind of locking.

Comment: In this case maybe (considering we will use complex types) would be to chunk the list and process each one separately and combine the result after all.